# Android view reuse for viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on an app which uses viewpager with around 100-150 views in it, several views have webviews inside, however performance is poor, is there a way to reuse views like the viewholder pattern for listview, a similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450524/android-viewholder-for-viewpager) however I cannot convert my adapter to FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: try this http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/10/simple-viewpager-for-android.html. It uses an adapter.

Comment: that tutorial is just an implementation, there is not relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that view reuse is the default behavior,and you don't need to do anything excessive other than use override removeView method